# Decrypt Files in PHP (RIJNDAEL / sha 512)

Tags: php, security, encryption, cryptography

I have a pascal code that encrypts files using RIJNDAEL / sha 512 and send them to server, where they stay encrypted.

When a user request an encrypted file, I have to decrypt them using PHP.

The problem is: it seems that PHP only support to up RIJNDAEL 256, I found reference on the internet suggesting that only RIJNDAEL 128 is considered compatible with AES.

My question is: is there a way to decrypt these files in PHP using RIJNDAEL / sha 512? Or should I just "downgrade" the encryption to RIJNDAEL 128/256?

Ideally I'd like the most secure encryption. I do have the choice in Delphi as I'm using a library that offer pretty much all popular encryption methods, but the issue is how to find an encryption method that's both *very* secure and handled by PHP.

Thanks!

PS. please keep in mind that I'm a newbie when it comes to encryption!

Comment: You don't understand the difference between a block cipher and message digest function.    SHA512 is a message digest function being used a s2k function and can be found in the mhash extension for php.  Also sha512 isn't a very good s2k function.

Comment: There is no algorithm named Rijndael/SHA-512. So you will have to ask expicitly how that encryption algorithm and hash algorithm are used together. Probably SHA-512 is used as key derivation mechanism and AES (a restricted version of Rijndael) is used to encrypt files. You will need to know the *mode* and *padding mechanism* to be able to know how to encrypt/decrypt.

Comment: @Rook no offense meant, but please keep in mind that you are not offering an answer to a crypto expert. s2k only scores "Honda" references for google, and I don't see you mentioning scrypt anywhere. Sorry for the critique, in a bar I would've offered you a beer for the trouble I caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is: it seems that PHP only support to up RIJNDAEL 256, I found reference on the internet suggesting that only RIJNDAEL 128 is considered compatible with AES.

You're confusing the **block** size with the **key** size.

AES supports 128, 192 and 256 bits keys with a 128 bits block size.

Rijndael **also** supports 192 and 256 bits block size - but those are generally not used by default (e.g. in .NET) so it *should* not be an issue to interoperate between PHP and Delphi - review the source code to be sure and try it out :-)

Comment: To make above a bit more clear: Rijndael is actually a rather configurable algorithm. AES is a restricted version of Rijndael, choosen by NIST as winner of the AES competition. They have choosen a certain block size (128 bits) and three key sizes, 128, 192 and 256 bits. For each key size, a certain number of internal rounds are executed: 10, 12 and 14 respectively.